# Review Redux-Sagas implementation

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am learning reactjs with redux-saga and i want to go deeper in my competencies so i made a little sample where i have implemented a redux-sagas, please guys can you check if my implementation is good?
If not tell me what you think i have to change to make it better.

PS: i focus only in the sagas implementation so the other things like configuration or repo architecture are not optimized.

You can find the repository here at this link https://github.com/Francoisbeche/Test-sagas/tree/master/src

Comment: my code works, i want a review for best practice and improve my implementation.

Comment: looks good / on the right track... You might want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com to ask for code reviews